# MVC: Views does not update

Tags: java, swing, jpa, model-view-controller, netbeans

At first This app was built without database It 's works well.
But after I modified it to work with database ,the views become not responding when call the deposit or delete account function. but the database transaction is work normally. I don't know why please help me

this is Institute

```
 public class Institute extends Observable {


private String name;
private String contactPerson;
private String telephone;
private String address;
private List<Account> accountList;

private static Institute instance;

private  List<Account> getAccountsFromDB() {
    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Lab12WithDBPU");
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    List<Account> accounts = em.createNamedQuery("Account.findAll").getResultList();
    return accounts;
}

private Institute(){
    accountList = getAccountsFromDB();


}//end cons

public static Institute getInstance(){
    //follow singleton design pattern

    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new Institute();
    }//end if

    return instance ;
}//end method

public static int addData (Account e) {
    persist(e);
    return 1;
}
public static void removeData (Account e) {
     EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Lab12WithDBPU");
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
     Account employee = em.find(Account.class, e.getAccountId());

     em.getTransaction().begin();
    em.remove(employee);
     em.getTransaction().commit();
}

public void closeAccount(String accountId) throws IllegalArgumentException {


    Account deleteAccount = findAccountById(accountId);

    //not found the account object
    if (deleteAccount == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The Account ID not found");
    }//end if

    //can't delete current that have saving
    if (deleteAccount.getAccountType() == AccountType.CURRENT && this.accountList.size() > 1) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Can't Delete \"Current\" Account Type that have \"Saving\" Accounts Type");
    }//end method

    //can't delete current that have balance > 0
    if (deleteAccount.getAccountType() == AccountType.CURRENT && deleteAccount.getBalance() != 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The Balance of \"Current\" Account Type Must be 0 to Delete");
    }//end method

    //get the current to deposit
    Account currentAccount = accountList.get(0);

    //if selected account to delete has balance > 0 then deposite the account from the list, else don't
    if (deleteAccount.getBalance() > 0) {
        currentAccount.deposit(deleteAccount.getBalance());

    }//end if       

    accountList.remove(deleteAccount);

    deleteAccount.notifyAfterDelete();
    removeData(deleteAccount);

}//end method

public void createAccount(String accountId, AccountType accountType) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    //check duplication
    if ( isAccountIdAlreadyExist(accountId) ) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("This Account ID Already Exsist");
    }//end if

    //must open current first
    if ( this.accountList.isEmpty() && accountType != AccountType.CURRENT ) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Must Open \"Current\" Account Type First");
    }//end if

    //current can have only one
    if ( !this.accountList.isEmpty() && accountType == AccountType.CURRENT ) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot Open Multiple \"Current\" Accounts Type");
    }//end if

    //create object


    Account account = new Account(0, accountId, accountType );
    accountList.add(account);

    //register the views with the model in case of the account have just create after run
    for (Observer observer : RensselearBankSystem.MODEL_OBSERVER_LIST) {
        account.addObserver(observer);

    }//end for

    //tell the view to update
    account.notifyAfterCreate();
    addData(account);


}//end method

public String getTotalBalance(){
    String result = "";

    for (Account account : this.accountList) {
        result += account.toString() +"\n";            
    }//end for

    return null;
}//end method

private boolean isAccountIdAlreadyExist(String accountId) {

    if (findAccountById(accountId)!=null)
        return true;
    return false;

}//end method

public List<Account> getAccountList() {
    return this.accountList;

}//end method

public Account findAccountById(String accountId) {
    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Lab12WithDBPU");
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    return em.find(Account.class,accountId);
}//end method

public static void persist(Object object) {
    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Lab12WithDBPU");
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    try {
        em.persist(object);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        em.getTransaction().rollback();
    } finally {
        em.close();
    }
}



 }//end class
```

this is Account Class

```
@Entity
@NamedQueries({
  @NamedQuery(name = "Account.findAll", query = "SELECT e FROM Account e")})
   public class Account extends Observable implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private String accountId;
private Integer odLimit;
private Integer balance;
private Integer typeCode;
private AccountType accountType;

public Account() {
}

public Account(Integer balance, String accountID, AccountType accountType) {
    odLimit = accountType == AccountType.CURRENT ? 2000 : 0 ;
    this.balance = balance;
    this.accountId = accountID;
    this.accountType = accountType;
    if(this.accountType.equals(AccountType.CURRENT))
        typeCode = 1;
    else
        typeCode = 2;


}//end cons   

 public void deposit(Integer amount) throws IllegalArgumentException{

     EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Lab12WithDBPU");
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    Account depositAccount = em.find(Account.class, this.accountId);

    em.getTransaction().begin();

    //amout must be > 0 to deposit
    if (amount <= 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The Amount must be more than 0");
    }//end if

    this.balance += amount;
    depositAccount.balance += amount;

    //tell the views
    setChanged();
    notifyObservers();
    em.getTransaction().commit();


}//end method
 public static int addData (Account e) {
    persist(e);
    return 1;
}



public void notifyAfterCreate(){
    System.out.println(this.toString());
    System.out.println("notifyAfterCreate");
    //tell the views
    setChanged();
    notifyObservers();

}//end method

public void notifyAfterDelete(){
    System.out.println(this.toString());
    System.out.println("notifyAfterDelete");
    //tell the views
    setChanged();
    notifyObservers();

}//end method

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "[" +this.accountId +", " +this.accountType +", " +this.balance +"]";
}//end method

public String getId() {
    return accountId;
}

public void setId(String accountId) {
    this.accountId = accountId;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 0;
    hash += (accountId != null ? accountId.hashCode() : 0);
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
    if (!(object instanceof Account)) {
        return false;
    }
    Account other = (Account) object;
    if ((this.accountId == null && other.accountId != null) || (this.accountId != null && !this.accountId.equals(other.accountId))) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}


public Integer getBalance() {
    return balance;
}//end method

public String getAccountId() {
    return accountId;
}//end method

public AccountType getAccountType() {
    return accountType;
}//end method

public static void persist(Object object) {
    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Lab12WithDBPU");
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    try {
        em.persist(object);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        em.getTransaction().rollback();
    } finally {
        em.close();
    }
}

}
```

this is View

```
 public class StudentView extends javax.swing.JFrame implements Observer {

/**
 * Creates new form StudentView
 */
public StudentView() {
    System.out.println("init admin");
    initComponents();

    setComponentHandles();
    JTableManager.initTable(jTable_studentView, Institute.getInstance().getAccountList());
    registerView();  // register view for the old account from database

}//end cons

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() { .....

}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton jButton_deposit;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton_withdraw;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel_amout;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel_selectedAccount;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel_studentInput;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel_studentView;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel_total;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel_studentInput;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel_studentView;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel_summary;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane_studentView;
private javax.swing.JTable jTable_studentView;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField_amout;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField_selectedAccount;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField_total;
// End of variables declaration                   

@Override
public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
    //call support method
    JTableManager.initTable(this.jTable_studentView, Institute.getInstance().getAccountList());
    System.out.println("Student update");
    //update total after add/remove change the account
    updateTotal();

}//end method

private void setComponentHandles() {
    //register observer with the components
    this.jTable_studentView.addMouseListener(new SelectStudentViewTableRowListener(this));
    this.jButton_deposit.addActionListener( new DepositListener(this) );
    this.jButton_withdraw.addActionListener( new WithdrawListener(this) );

}//end method

private void updateTotal() {
    List<Account> accountList = Institute.getInstance().getAccountList() ;
    int sum = 0;

    for (Account account : accountList) {
        sum += account.getBalance() ;
    }//end for

    this.jTextField_total.setText("" +sum);

}//end method


/*
 getters, setters
 */

private void registerView() {
    List<Account> accountList = Institute.getInstance().getAccountList();
    for(Account account : accountList){
                account.addObserver(this);
                System.out.println(account.getAccountId()+"add observer student\n");
    }
}
```

}//end class

And  this is main class

```
 public class RensselearBankSystem {
//list of the views to accessed by controllers and models
public static final List<Observer> MODEL_OBSERVER_LIST = new ArrayList<Observer>();

public static void main(String[] args) {        
    StudentView studentView = new StudentView();
    AdministratorView administratorView = new AdministratorView();


    //set position of second frame
    Point point = studentView.getLocation();
    point.y += 340;
    administratorView.setLocation(point);


    //add the views to the list
    System.out.println("start add to list");
    RensselearBankSystem.MODEL_OBSERVER_LIST.add(studentView);
    RensselearBankSystem.MODEL_OBSERVER_LIST.add(administratorView); 
    System.out.println("finish add to list");

    studentView.setVisible(true);
    administratorView.setVisible(true);



}//end main
 }//end class
```

the code is very long So, I uploaded the full project [click to download my netbeans project](http://www.mediafire.com/download/vvd1eaf1h9hjj29/Lab12WithDB.rar)

Comment: did you use the debugger alrady to verify where youre faoult may be?

Comment: If anyone want to run the project please create the database first dbname : accountDb username : aom passwoed: aom

Comment: No one will have the time to go through your project or run it I'm afraid, but it sounds as if you have a Swing Concurrency issue. Google Concurrency in Swing and read the tutorial. Or better, here's the tutorial link: [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/).

Comment: @lordkain did you mean to rigth click and choose "debug" ? I 've just try it look like it 's not help.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels thankyou for  . I 've try to show the output to see if the Observer call the update() after the model call notifyObserver(),The result is the Observer not call the update method  .  So, I think the problem is not about the GUI.

Comment: Does your GUI become non-responsive? Then it's **all** about Swing concurrency. You don't have to accept this advice if you don't want to, but if you do decide not to accept it, I hope you have a better answer up your sleeve.

Comment: Sorry if I make you angry. It's my fault . but please look public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
        System.out.println("Admin update");
        //call support method
        JTableManager.initTable(this.jTable_administratorView,Institute.getInstance().getAccountList());
        
        
    }//end method  I try to show you that it's not work all of this method including the System.out.println();

Comment: I'm not angry, but please answer a simple initial question: does your GUI become completely non-responsive?

Comment: No, It's not completely non-responsive. It 's work when I create account and the update() method is work so.

Comment: Please clarify? Does it ever become unresponsive, and if so, when?

Comment: Attually, It's not work with  withdraw,deposit, delete Account only.

Comment: I think I used wrong word. I  mean the view is not respond to some function. But with other function it work. It's not unresponsive forever.

Comment: @cherry: OK, sorry, then it might not be a concurrency issue, my bad, and my apologies. Time for you to do some debugging either with a debugger or with println statements. The key of course: isolate and find the error.